# How to detect which field has been updated in afterUpdate|beforeUpdate GORM methods

Tags: grails, grails-orm, aop

i use afterUpdate method reflected by GORM API in grails project.

```
class Transaction{

    Person receiver;
    Person sender;


}
```

i want to know which field modified to make `afterUpdate` behaves   accordingly :

```
class Transaction{
     //...............
   def afterUpdate(){
      if(/*Receiver is changed*/){
        new TransactionHistory(proKey:'receiver',propName:this.receiver).save();
      }
      else
      {
      new TransactionHistory(proKey:'sender',propName:this.sender).save();
      }

   }
}
```

I can use `beforeUpdate`: and catch up the object before updating  in global variable (previous as Transaction), then in afterUpdate, compare `previous` with the current object. 
Could be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically this would be done by using the [isDirty](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/isDirty.html) method on your domain instance. For example:

```
// returns true if the instance value of firstName 
// does not match the persisted value int he database.
person.isDirty('firstName')
```

However, in your case if you are using `afterUpdate()` the value has already been persisted to the database and `isDirty` won't ever return true.

You will have to implement your own checks using `beforeUpdate`. This could be setting a transient value that you later read. For example:

```
class Person {
  String firstName
  boolean firstNameChanged = false
  static transients = ['firstNameChanged']
  ..
  def beforeUpdate() {
    firstNameChanged = this.isDirty('firstName')
  }
  ..
  def afterUpdate() {
    if (firstNameChanged)
    ...
  }
...
}
```

Comment: thk u. But it means that for each field we have 2 fields (<field> and<field>Changed )

Comment: Or you use `beforeUpdate()`. Tracking changes using transients as I pointed out is the only other solution if you are using `afterUpdate()`

Comment: does seem a wasDirty would come in handy